Redirect in apache from ip+port to host name
Please help me figure it out.
A simple redirection from the IP to the name works.
<VirtualHost *:80>    
    ServerName 11.111.11.111
    Redirect "/" "https://www.mydomen.com/"
</VirtualHost>

How do I redirect from IP + port?
11.111.11.111:1111 to https://www.mydomen.com/
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 11.111.11.111:1111
    ServerAlias 11.111.11.111*
    Redirect "/" "https://www.mydomen.com/"
</VirtualHost>

It doesn't work that way.

11.111.11.111:1111 is not a valid server name. It is a combination of a name and a port, but that is not a name. You probably want something like that:
<VirtualHost *:1111>
    ServerName 11.111.11.111
    Redirect "/" "https://www.mydomen.com/"
</VirtualHost>

Keep in mind that you also need to enable your http server to actually listen on that port 1111 for incoming requests. So you need to open that port in your firewall.

Thanks for the reply. Please tell me how to make it apply to any port?

What do you mean with that? What does "it" refer to here? And what does "any port" actually mean? I assume you are able to adapt the <VirtualHost *:1111> to any port you like. So maybe you wonder how to make the http server listen to any port, so actually all ports at once somehow? That is not possible, you need to bind it to specific ports, those ports are blocked for any other service then. The other way round the http server cannot bind to any port already used by any other service. That simply is not how ports are meant to be used. And I wonder why you should want such thing.

Please advise me how to do it better in my case.
I have several web applications installed on my server using docker. Each is linked to a specific address via apache, for example site1.mydomen.com, site2.mydomen.com ... You can log in to each web application using the IP (11.111.11.111:1111, 11.111.11.111:2222 ...  How can I block IP access to these web applications?

That is typically done via local name resolution, not using different ports. That is the whole idea behind virtual hosts in http servers: all hosts share the same port, which host is requested is determined by the HTTP_HOST header inside the request, so by the name used in the browser when entering the URL.

What I don't understand in your last comment: why do you say "block" now all of a sudden? In your question you wrote of redirecting, why ever.

It is necessary to make sure that no one can get to the server by entering the IP address:port. To do this, you must either block or redirect. And I don't understand how to do it.

You don't have to when you are using virtual hosts. Please read about that. It is documented. Inside the apache http server you declare one virtual host per such application. That host responds to any request that has the header HTTP_HOST set with that name configured for that virtual host. All other requests, so also any requests to ip address are responded to by the default host, that is the first virtual host found in the configuration of the http server, typically called _default or similar. In that host you can deny access.

Thanks for the reply.
Yes, that's how it's organized for me.
But what should I write in the default host to prohibit access to the IP address?

A general RequireAll denied for the main location. That uses the access module. No rewriting required, though you could achieve the same by means of the rewriting module.
